# Display "Seq_no" and "primary_term" in Elastic's response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to retrieve the "_seq_no" and "_primary_term" from my elastic search cluster, however it is not displaying in Kibana or when I run a search through my Java application.  I KNOW there's a setting or param I am missing to get this info back.  I've looked around, however I have not been able to find out where I need to make the changes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kibana, I just need to include it with the query

IE

```
{
  ...
  ...
  version : true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have changed since the accepted answer, or it may have been about retrieving. But the issue is relevant for search.

Normally, a GET on a document will return the version, the sequence number and the primary term. But a search does not. It only [returns the ID, index, document type and score (plus the document)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-response-body).

ElasticSearch 7 and later have a [`version` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#request-body-search-version) that adds the document `_version` to the return and a [`seq_no_primary_term` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#request-body-search-seq-no-primary-term) that adds the `seq_no` and `primary_term` to the return. Both can be supplied as a parameter or a value in the body.